# managing Postfix queue on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, postfix

Last year we moved our on-premise mail infrastructure running on Postfix to AWS, which went reasonable well. The only part I'm not too happy about yet is that whenever an instance dies (unexpectedly) / an EBS volume gets corrupted, we would lose all mail that still was being processed by that instance. I'm wondering if anyone else has a more robust design? Maybe putting the queue directory on EFS? If so, any pitfalls I should be aware of?

We have looked into moving to SES, but at our current volume (400k mails/day), the cost would be far too high.

Thanks!

Comment: Why does the instance die? This should not happen. Also your EBS volumes should use more robust filesystems such as XFS.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t spend your time trying to *work around* a crashing instance. Instead spend the time working out *why* is the instance crashing and *fix* the cause of that.

Is it overloaded? Running out of memory? Running out of CPU Credits? Check the monitoring tab and the server logs at the time it crashes and try to figure out what happend and why. Then perhaps increase the instance size (e.g. from t2.medium to m5.large) and see if it still breaks. Or add more swap space or more disk space or some postfix rate limiting, etc.

FWIW We’ve been running multiple Postfix servers on AWS for years and they are stable as rock.

Comment: So at the moment, our instances are quite stable and we haven't seen a crash yet. The thing is that EC2 is AZ-specific and we don't want to rely on a single availability zone for our critical services, which includes SMTP. We had a few occurrences in the past where one of our EBS volumes (of another service) got corrupted. Luckily that service replicates data amongst multiple instances so the loss of one instances doesn't impact availability nor incur data loss. If possible, we'd like to get the same level of redundancy with Postfix. Any idea on how to best achieve that? :)

Comment: Proper HA design requires a lot more information. What’s the critical part - inbound SMTP, outbound SMTP, other related services like IMAP? How many users would be affected by a downtime? Do they really need 100% SLA on email (unlikely)? How much are you willing to invest into a solution for a problem that may never occur at all (AZ failures are very rare). The more complex you make it the more likely some component fails. It may be the easiest to run it as it is and in the unlikely event of a crash accept the small downtime and restore manually.

Comment: 100% SLA isn’t strictly necessary, the critical part for us is that once an inbound instance queues a specific mail, that mail shouldn’t be lost due to an EBS failure (which  agree is rare, but I’ve had it happen a few times). Which instance in the end handles the mail or what delay it may have is less of an issue. Afaik, Postfix itself has no HA feature for its queue system built-in, so I imagine the final solution will be a bit of work, which is fine.